# Formatting multi-line code snippets in the Azure APIM Developer Portal

Tags: azure-api-management

I love the APIM Developer Portal and love having it tied to APIM but I am running across some issues trying to build the content out within the portal.  I have a multi-line HTML/Javascript code snippet that I would like to include on a page but when I switch to the text style to "Formatted" each line becomes its own block.  Ideally it would be one block (grey background has no white spaces).  I could format it in an IDE and include an image but that limits the consumers ability to copy and paste to I wanted to avoid the image.

Are there any tips for how to include code snippets in the developer portal?

[image]

Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This happens because of **\n** converted to **< p >** on copy/paste text content but you need **< br />**

In the text editor **Enter** key or **\n** converted to **< p >**

**Ctrl + Enter** key converted to **< br />**

The current workaround is to replace all **< p >** to **< br />** with **Ctrl + Enter**

Comment: Thank you! - I will try that